# Getting lastest update file in Power BI Folder Source

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a folder with 3 different subfolders where I store some daily exports. I want to get only the latest updated file from each folder path. As I show in the pic.

[image: Current problem]

I need to keep the binary and the attributes columns of the latest "date modified" file for each same path. The latest date modified is different for each different subfolder. My subfolders refere to each month of the year (their name are May, Jun, July and soon it will be incorporated August).

*In this way, as I have 3 different folder paths values in my column Folder Path, I will only have 3 csv to expand.*

I have tried to group by folder path and maximum Date modified, but I lost the other fields. If I add, maximun of attributes or all rows, does not solve me problem either.

I also tried this solution: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Keep-only-the-latest-date-for-duplicate-entries/td-p/638447

But I get stuck in an error: **Function type value cannot be converted to Table type. Details: Value = [Function], Type = [Type].**

M Query code:

```
 let
    Source = AzureStorage.DataLake(".../usersDailyData"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transformar archivo", each #"Transformar archivo"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transformar archivo"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transformar archivo", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transformar archivo"(#"Archivo de ejemplo"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{ Columns name here })
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Any ideas to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you include the m-query script so we understand better what we are looking at..

Comment: Added. It is a folder, and it contains some minor folders created each month, each day of the month a csv file is uploaded with the data of the day and previous days, that's why I only need to keep the latest csv.Then, I have to expand the last updated csv for each different value of the folder column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a column that has the max datetime for each Folder Path, then comparing each rows datetime to that max, and filtering out non-matches.  Along the lines of below.  I think it goes after the **Invoke Custom Function1** step , but you can move it where needed

```
...    
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoke Custom Function1","MaxDate",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows( #"Invoke Custom Function1", each [Folder Path]=i[Folder Path]) [Date modified]), type datetime ),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each if [Date modified]=[MaxDate] then "keep" else null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom] = "keep")),
...
```